# How to UrlEncode a Sha1 string for a torrent tracker

Tags: c#, .net, url, bittorrent, torrent

I try to send an HTTP request to a Torrent Tracker that must be with this form:

`bt1.archive.org
GET /announce?info_hash=ACC3B2E433D7C7475ABB5941B5681CB7A1EA26E2 HTTP/1.1
Host: bt1.archive.org
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html
User-Agent: CSharp`

But the `info_hash` parameter must be UrlEncoded and it must look like: `%AC%C3%B2%E4%33%D7%C7%47%5A%BB%59%41%B5%68%1C%B7%A1%EA%26%E2`, So I use

```csharp
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(info_hash)
```

And the output is the same as the input.
I think the answer of this problem is obvious, but I didn't found it...

Comment: Maybe this will work: `System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(sha1.ComputeHash(BencodeUtility.Encode(kvp.Value).ToArray()))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sha1 hash is 20 bytes long. The 40 characters long hex string is just used for humans. So you need to hex-decode before url-encoding.